# How i can prevent double selection on dynamic javascript drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am using both javascript and laravel to manipulate a form.

Laravel to get values from database to populate the form and javascript to add dynamic drop down to allow multiple entry..

Everything is working except now I need to add a new task to prevent double selection, that is after I have selected a name, I should not be able to select it in the next dynamic drop down.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var postURL = "http://localhost/bcwater/public/addmore";
  var i = 1;

  $('.addRow').on('click', function() {
    i++;
    addRow();
  });

  function addRow() {
    var tr = '<tr class="dynamic-added">' +
      '<td>' +
      '<select ng-model="marketers" id="marketers" class="form-control marketers" name="marketers[]">' +
      '<option value="">Select Marketer </option>  @foreach($marketers as $data)' +
      '<option value="{{$data->first_name}}">{{$data->first_name}} {{ $data->last_name }}</option> @endforeach' +
      '</select>' +
      '</td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" name="target[]"  id="target' + i + '" class="form-control" oninput="calc()" /> </td>' +
      '<td><span id="result' + i + '">0</span> </td>' +
      '<td> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove">- </a> </td>' +

      '</tr>';
    $('tbody').append(tr);
  };

  $('tbody').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select ng-model="marketers" class="form-control marketers" name="marketers[]" required ng-init="marketers = '{{ old('marketers') }}'">
          <option value="">Select Marketer </option>
          @foreach($marketers as $data)
          <option value="{{$data->first_name}}">{{$data->first_name}} {{ $data->last_name }}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </td>

      <td>
        <input type="text" name="target[]" class="form-control target" id="target" oninput="calc()">
      </td>
      <td><span id="sum1" onchange="calc()">0</span> </td>
      <td> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove">- </a> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is not a laravel question. Please update the snippet I made with RELEVANT HTML and no PHP

Comment: This is not valid JS: `'<option value="">Select Marketer </option>     @foreach($marketers as $data)'+`

Comment: this options are laravel dynamic values